# Changing a mailto:link causing error #1056

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am editing a Flash file and I need to change a mailto: link. When I edit that link to change the email address I get several instances of error #1056.

I am no Flash guru, I am just wondering why such an arbitrary change would break everything and where I should be looking to solve the problem/

Thanks

Edit: 
Here are the errors:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property baseBackground on com.***t.csg.view.CSGWebsite.
ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property backgroundHolder on com.***.csg.view.CSGWebsite.
ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property backgroundMergeHolder on com.***.csg.view.CSGWebsite.
ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property content on com.***t.csg.view.CSGWebsite.
ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property busyVisual on com.***.csg.view.CSGWebsite.
ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property nav0 on com.***.csg.view.CSGWebsite.
ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property nav1 on com.***.csg.view.CSGWebsite.
ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property nav2 on com.***.csg.view.CSGWebsite.
ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property homeHotspot on com.***.csg.view.CSGWebsite.
```

I am totally confused, as **some of the errors have no ActionScript assigned to them**, such as baseBackground.

Comment: That sounds very strange indeed, however, that error comes with a description of where things went wrong, doesn't that tell you anything?

Comment: It might help to post the before and after, especially the 2 or 3 lines around where Flash is telling you the error is.

Comment: I added the errors. They all point from various elements to com.***.view.CSGWebsite (this is the most anti-semantic Flash file in the world! :( )

Comment: There are no problems if I leave the mailto link as xxx@xxx.xxx,  but if I change it to yyy@xxx.xxx it pumps those errors out and the opening screen refresh loops/

Comment: @danixd I should have been more clear and said to post the code since that is what we need to see. Not all of it - just the 2-3 lines before and after the change.

Comment: do you mean the actionscript? All I am doing is changing the mailto link in the properties view.

Comment: does the flash work if you leave it at the original value and export?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can export okay with one email and not with another, this won't likely be the solution, but it's worth a try.

This is a error that is common to get when there's a conflict between the class and the stage instances flash tries to declare on it. It's usually related to changing the "Automatically declare stage instances", some prefer it on, some prefer it off.

Try toggling it and see what happens.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/creating_as3_components_pt2/fig05.gif

Comment: Solved the problem, it came down to a hidden duplicate of the link. Thanks for the help!